# How to automatically fix the indentations of a nested markup page?

Tags: javascript, html, emacs, indentation

I got this markup on Emacs:

```
     <div class ...>
     <div class 2 ...>
<div class  ="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
           <div class    ="modal-dialog">
      <div class     ="modal-content">
  <form id   ="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/contact">
```

Is there a simple way to format this code in Emacs by its hierarchy so that it will be more readable?, like so:

```
<div class ...>
     <div class 2 ...>
        <div class  ="modal fade" id="contactModal" tabindex="0" role="dialog">
           <div class    ="modal-dialog">
             <div class     ="modal-content">
                <form id   ="contactForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/contact">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`M-x indent-region`, usually bound to `<TAB>`.

Works on regions, so you need to mark the part of document you want to indent, or `C-x h` to mark the whole buffer.

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Indentation.html